# On Ionic-Angular, bower components has been ignore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, bower

I am trying to use a Cordova Plugin, I installed with bower, and getting an error in the browser console:
`GET http://localhost:8100/bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js`
 this is the file structure

[image]

and here, this is what I have in my `index.html`

```
<script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files can only be loaded when they are in the `www` directory. By default, Ionic installs bower packages into the `www/lib` directory.

`$ ionic add ngCordova` Run this from your project root in the CLI.

This will install ngCordova into the correct directory. Then add the script at this path.

`<script src="lib/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>`

Comment: and what can I do to move the folder bower into www ? it is weird because I have never tell to the system to put bower folder outside of www folder

Comment: Did you remove the `.bowerrc` file from the project? Ionic will put this there when you start a project, but if you delete it then it will use the default path instead. This is what it should be https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/blob/master/.bowerrc

Comment: I add that file now because I never deleted, but it wasn't there, now what should I do ? bower install ?

Comment: Yes, you can run `bower install` to have it reinstall into the correct directory.